# How to get Count of total users how have opened a account in last 5 years and group them by their Credit score

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables as mentioned below to grab data from and group on.

1) `DATE` table has `accountOpen` column
2) `USER` table has `userid`  column
3) `Userscore` table has `creditscore` column

Now I have to write a query to give me Count of all users who have opened an account in the last 5 years. I have to put them in Credit score buckets from '<600', '601-700', '>700' based on their score during their account open date. I need `distinct` count of all users. How can I query that in SQL? I have something like below so far but it does not give me what I want.

```
Select 
CASE WHEN T.accountopen between '2019/01/01' and getdate() THEN '2019'
    WHEN T.accountopen between '2018/01/01' and '2018/12/31' THEN '2018'
    as YEAROpened,

CASE WHEN US.creditscore <640 then '<600',
WHEN US.creditscore <640 then '601-700',
WHEN US.creditscore <640 then '>700' as creditscore,

Count (u.userid) as NumberofUsers
FROM DATE T
JOIN USER US
ON US.id = T.id
JOIN UserScore U
on U.userid = US.userid
WHERE T.accountopen > '2015/01/01'
GROUP by T.accountopen,US.creditscore
```

Comment: Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: I believe you can remove your case for account open and group by year(date_opened)

Comment: What do your table structures look like? Do you get an error message or are the results just inaccurate? Looking at your query it appears the second part of your case statement is probably not what you want - since you want scores between 601 and 700 you probably want `US.creditscore > 600 and US.creditscore <= 700`.  Right now the second and third parts of the case statement both check for `< 640`.

Comment: so, say suppose 10 users opened an account in 2018 who's score is <600
10 users opened account in 2019 whose score is 650
and 10 people opened an account in 2017 who's score is >700

My query should group something like below:

YEAROpened     creditscore            NumberofUsers
-------------------------------------------------------------
2017           >640                    10
2018           601 - 700               10
2019           >700                    10

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Your US.creditscore case when statement has the same check for each. I think you need it to look like this.

```
CASE WHEN US.creditscore <= 600 then '<600',
WHEN US.creditscore BETWEEN 601 AND 700 then '601-700',
WHEN US.creditscore > 700 then '>700' as creditscore,
...
```

Also the current group by will return multiple rows per year. I think you want your group by to group by the year only and disregard the month and day.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN YEAR(T.accountopen) = '2019' THEN '2019'
    WHEN YEAR(T.accountopen) = '2018' THEN '2018'
    as YEAROpened,

CASE WHEN US.creditscore <= 600 then '<600',
WHEN US.creditscore BETWEEN 601 AND 700 then '601-700',
WHEN US.creditscore > 700 then '>700' as creditscore,

Count (u.userid) as NumberofUsers
FROM DATE T
JOIN USER US
ON US.id = T.id
JOIN UserScore U
on U.userid = US.userid
WHERE T.accountopen > '2015/01/01'
GROUP by YEAR(T.accountopen), CASE WHEN US.creditscore <= 600 then '<600',
WHEN US.creditscore BETWEEN 601 AND 700 then '601-700',
WHEN US.creditscore > 700 then '>700'
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I did make that change. However I am not getting a grouped results I am getting multiple counts under 2018 for <600 instead of total count of 10

Comment: can you sum them in an outer query? For example:
SELECT YEAROpened,  creditscore, SUM(NumberofUsers) FROM
(...original query here)

Comment: Ah I think it's because you are grouping by accountopen which will be different for each date. Try editing your group by to GROUP by YEAR(T.accountopen) ,US.creditscore

Comment: Try this answer, but for the date comparing use proper SQL date formatting such as "'01.01.2015 00:00:00'". Good luck!

Comment: Or try subtracting 5 years from todays date and using that for comparisn. "DateAdd(yy, -5, GetDate())"

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones thanks for the edit, apparently I can't spell BETWEEN lol ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

```
Select YEAR(T.ACCOUNTOPEN) as YearOpened,
   CASE WHEN US.creditscore <640 then '<600'
        WHEN US.creditscore <640 then '601-700'
        WHEN US.creditscore <640 then '>700' END as creditscore,
  Count (u.userid) as NumberofUsers
FROM DATE T
JOIN USER US ON US.id = T.id
JOIN UserScore U on U.userid = US.userid
WHERE YEAR(T.accountopen) > 2014
GROUP by YEAR(T.accountopen) ,
      CASE WHEN US.creditscore <640 then '<600'
        WHEN US.creditscore <640 then '601-700'
        WHEN US.creditscore <640 then '>700' END
```